# Javascript firebase.database().ref.on(...) returns null

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm throwing in the towel. I just can't seem to figure this out. I've set up a firebase app and just trying to do a simple request for the data, but it returns null. My database is currently set to public so there shouldn't be any permission issues. I can successfully authenticate using an npm package, `react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth` and get user information back so it's working to some degree, but I just can't get data from the database.  I've gone over the docs many, many times and tried searching for the issue here, but can't seem to find anything. I tried to be thorough. So here's basically what I have...

```js
// The actual config in the code is copied directly from the firebase general settings page, so if it isn't right, it isn't right on their page.
const  config = {
  apiKey: "someKey",
  authDomain: "myAppId.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://myAppId.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "myAppId",
  storageBucket: "myAppId.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "mySenderId"
};
const handleSnapshot = (snapshotVal) => {
    console.log(snapshotVal);
    // Using react hence the setState, but this and the console.log return null
    this.setState({data: snapshotVal});
}

firebase.initializeApp(config);

database = firebase.database()
countriesRef = database.ref('countries');
countriesRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    handleSnapshot(snapshot.val());
});
```

I've also tried...
`countriesRef = database.ref('/countries');`
...and...
`countriesRef = database.ref('/countries/');`
...and just to be extra sure, I've copied/pasted the name right out of firebase.

Here's a screengrab of the database...

[image: Firebase Screengrab]

Comment: Also, did some debugging and I see an object for the snapshot from the function callback of countriesRef.on, but val() isn't part of that object and I don't really see anything in there that would be grabbing that data.

Comment: Can you console the value of snapshot?

Comment: {snapshot: DataSnapshot}
snapshot: DataSnapshot
index_: PriorityIndex {}
key: (...)
node_: ChildrenNode {children_: SortedMap, priorityNode_: null, indexMap_: IndexMap, lazyHash_: ""}
ref: (...)
ref_: Reference {repo: Repo, path: Path, queryParams_: QueryParams, orderByCalled_: false}
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object

Comment: @Phil I tried const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config); and used firebaseApp instead, but still got null.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale sorry for the cryptic paste, but these comments don't do well with returns, spacing, etc. Hopefully that was helpful. Let me know if you're looking for something specific.

Comment: Your screenshots look like you're using Cloud Firestore and not the Realtime Database. For that you want `firebase.firestore()`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Comment: Thanks @Phil. Can you elaborate on that. It gives me an error `Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)` if I add .firestore().

Comment: No idea, sorry. Sounds like you're trying to initialise the app multiple times. Since the Cloud Firestore is still in beta, you might be more comfortable moving your collections over to the Realtime Database

Comment: Oh, wait... I see what you're saying here. I think I'm on the right path now. Thank you so much @Phil, I bet I can figure it out from here. I'll post an answer regarding your suggestion once it's fixed.

Comment: @Phil you were right. In the interest of time, I'm just switching it over to the Realtime Database since that's what works with the above code. It's just for a quick little app I'm doing for my wife. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, @Phil, if you'd like the credit for an answer, feel free to post it and I'll mark yours as the answer. It really isn't that obvious in the docs to know what's going on there.

Comment: To get rid of the "already exists" put `if (firebase.apps.length === 0)` around the call to `firebase.initializeApp(config)`. So `if (firebase.apps.length === 0) firebase.initializeApp(config);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase provides 2 different kinds of databases: [Realtime](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) database and [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/).

From the screenshot, I see that you are using Firestore database, but you are connecting to the Realtime database.

First, initialize the Firebase (in your example it is fine):

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Then, you need to connect to Firestore:

```
// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
const db = firebase.firestore();

// Disable deprecated features
db.settings({
  timestampsInSnapshots: true
});
```

Now, when you are connected is time for your first request:

```
const countriesRef = db.collection("countries");

countriesRef.get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.data())
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting countries:", error);
    });
```